# How can I make a variable the epicenter of the screen in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small browser game like agar.io where a small cell eats small circles to get larger, I want it to be that whenever the cell moves, the screen moves with it so that no matter how far I move the cell, it is always at the circle of the screen. I'm not sure how I would accomplish this using javascript and jquery. I can't find any tutorials online. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is what the game looks like so far.
[image]

```
var array1 = [];
var larger = 80;
function circles(){
    var colours = ["blue","red","orange","yellow","purple","green"];
    var circlesList = [];
    var coordinatesLeft = [];
    var coordinatesRight = [];
    

    for (x = 0; x<=80; x++){
        var circlesDiv = "<div id ='circle"+x+"' class = 'circle' style ='background-color:green; width: 25px; height:25px; border-radius:50%'></div> "; 
        $("#container3").append(circlesDiv);
        var randomColour = colours[Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length)];
        var randomTop = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
        var randomLeft = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2050) + 1);
        var randomSize = Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 15);
        // console.log(randomLeft);
        $('#circle'+x+'').css("left",randomLeft + "px");
        $('#circle'+x+'').css("top",randomTop + "px");
        $('#circle'+x+'').css("height",randomSize + "px");
        $('#circle'+x+'').css("width",randomSize + "px");
        $('#circle'+x+'').css("background-color",randomColour);
        var circleLeft = $('#circle'+x+'').css("left");
        var circleTop = $('#circle'+x+'').css("top");
        var circlesGeneral = x;
        window.array1[circleLeft+"_"+circleTop] = circlesGeneral;
        // masiv[left_top] = id




    }
}
function takeoveractual(){
    var bigCellLeft = $("#movingBlock").position().left;
    var bigCellTop = $("#movingBlock").position().top;
    for (var ele in window.array1){
        var splitting = ele.split("_");
        splits1 = splitting[0].replace("px","");
        splits2 = splitting[1].replace("px","");
        bigCellLeft *=1;
        bigCellTop *=1;
        splits1 *=1;
        splits2 *=1;
        var difference1 = bigCellLeft - splits1;
        var difference2 = bigCellTop - splits2;
        if (difference1 <0){
            difference1*=-1;
        } 
        if (difference2 <0){
            difference2*=-1;
        }
        if (difference1 <= larger && difference2 <=larger){
            $("#circle"+array1[splits1 + "px" + "_" + splits2 + "px"]).remove();
            var widthblock = $("#movingBlock").css("width");
            var heightblock = $("#movingBlock").css("height");
            widthblock = widthblock.replace("px","");
            widthblock *= 1;
            heightblock = heightblock.replace("px","");
            heightblock *= 1;
            $("#movingBlock").css("width",widthblock + 1 + "px");
            $("#movingBlock").css("height",heightblock + 1 + "px")
            window.larger += 1;
        }
        // if ($("#movingBlock").position().left - ele.position().left <=50 && $("#movingBlock").position().top - ele.position().top <=50){
        //  console.log("e;e");
        // }
    }

}
circles();  



$( window ).load(function() {
  shortcut.add("left",function() {
        leftClick();
    });

  shortcut.add("right",function() {
        rightClick();
    });

  shortcut.add("up",function() {
        upClick();
    });

  shortcut.add("down",function() {
        bottomClick();
    });
});


function leftClick(){
    var leftFunction = $("#movingBlock").position().left;
    leftFunction -= 50;
    $("#movingBlock").css("left",leftFunction + "px");
    $(".iconleft").css("color","green");
    $(".iconleft").css("font-size","52px");
    $(".iconright").css("color","black");
    $(".iconright").css("font-size","40px");
    $(".iconup").css("color","black");
    $(".iconup").css("font-size","40px");
    $(".icondown").css("color","black");
    $(".icondown").css("font-size","40px");
    takeoveractual();

}
function rightClick(){
    var leftFunction = $("#movingBlock").position().left;   
    leftFunction += 50;
    $("#movingBlock").css("left",leftFunction + "px");
    $(".iconright").css("color","green");
    $(".iconleft").css("color","black");
    $(".iconleft").css("font-size","40px");
    $(".iconup").css("color","black");
    $(".iconup").css("font-size","40px");
    $(".icondown").css("color","black");
    $(".icondown").css("font-size","40px");
    $(".iconright").css("font-size","52px");
    takeoveractual();
    
}
function upClick(){
    var upFunction = $("#movingBlock").position().top;
    upFunction -= 50;
    $("#movingBlock").css("top",upFunction + "px");
    $(".iconup").css("color","green");
    $(".iconup").css("font-size","52px");
    $(".iconleft").css("color","black");
    $(".iconleft").css("font-size","40px");
    $(".iconright").css("color","black");
    $(".iconright").css("font-size","40px");
    $(".icondown").css("color","black");
    $(".icondown").css("font-size","40px");
    takeoveractual();
}
function bottomClick(){
    var upFunction = $("#movingBlock").position().top;
    upFunction += 50;
    $("#movingBlock").css("top",upFunction + "px");
    $(".icondown").css("color","green") ;
    $(".icondown").css("font-size","52px");
    $(".iconleft").css("color","black");
    $(".iconleft").css("font-size","40px");
    $(".iconup").css("color","black");
    $(".iconup").css("font-size","40px");
    $(".iconright").css("color","black");
    $(".iconright").css("font-size","40px");
    takeoveractual();
}
```

Comment: Are you using a canvas?

Comment: Umm.. I'm not sure what a canvas is in programming (I'm not experienced in programming) but if you are talking about the small circles that are generated, I used a simple loop to create 80 circles of random colours, size and coordinates. Could you explain what you mean by canvas in this sense?

Comment: I not sure why anyone would upvote this (pretty picture?), please show your code and attempt. as-is its impossible to answer without seeing the mechanics of your script

Comment: This is a canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API . You will never have good enough performance for a game with a lot of movement (as agar.io) by creating html elements and moving them with jquery

Comment: You just have to think like Sun and Earth. We feel that the Sun is moving, but its us. Dont move your cell, put it centered on top, and move a global div in the background that contains all circles. When player hits "LEFT", move the div to the right.

Answer (score -1):

the answer to your question is simple: the center circle never moves. it stays fixed. that, in fact is the easiest part of your game.

now the real question is how do you get everything else to move?

Comment: Speaking from much experience, you actually *do* want the circle to move.  You want the camera target to seek and follow the player object, not just always be exactly on it.  On each frame, the camera should move X% of the way from where it is now to where the ideal centred view is.  The camera lag is actually how you get a sense for the momentum of the player object.

Comment: @Wyck, I'm not sure what you mean. according to the OP, it says, "always at the center of the screen", which means if it even moves 1 pixel, it's not meeting the very first requirement of the game.